# Spring Data JPA OrderBy don't work [small letter][capital letter] type parameter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi~ I was in trouble using Spring Data JPA.
this trouble github url : https://github.com/moregorenine/toyproject/tree/jpa_self_join_save/tree-structure-ztree

Development environment
spring-boot-starter-parent : 2.0.6.RELEASE + JPA + H2
spring data jpa reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Everything works fine. Except one.

don't work parameter type : [small letter][capital letter]... ex) tId

if change {tId} to {tempId} is good work!!! but I want use {tId}

ZTreeService.java

```
good work! no problem exmaple!!!

(O) zTrees = zTreeRepository.findAllByOrderById();
(O) zTrees = zTreeRepository.findAllByOrderByName();
(O) zTrees = zTreeRepository.findAllByOrderByIsParent();

don't work! only this type exmaple!!! why~

(X) zTrees = zTreeRepository.findAllByOrderByTId();
```

**tId type parameter possible create, insert from spring data JPA.
But Does 'OrderBy' method not support [small letter][capital letter] type parameter?**

ZTree.java

```
package com.github.moregorenine.ztree.domain;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
public class ZTree {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id; // 본인 id
    private String tId; // Ztree 내장 id
    @Transient
    private String parentTId; // Ztree 내장 pId
    @Transient
    private Long level; // lvl : 같은 그룹내 계층
    @NotBlank(message = "Name을 작성해주세요.")
    private String name;
    private String isParent;
    private String url; // 메뉴에 연결할 url
    private String useYn; // 메뉴 사용여부
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="pId")
    private ZTree parent;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<ZTree> children = new HashSet<ZTree>();
}
```

ZTreeService.java

```
@Service
public class ZTreeService {

    @Autowired
    private ZTreeRepository zTreeRepository;

    public List<ZTree> getAllZTrees() {
        List<ZTree> zTrees = new ArrayList<>();
        zTrees = zTreeRepository.findAllByOrderByTId();
        return zTrees;
    }
}
```

H2 Database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYEdl.png)

build failure message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
    Error creating bean with name 'ZTreeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'zTreeService';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
    Error creating bean with name 'ZTreeService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'zTreeRepository';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'ZTreeRepository': Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.github.moregorenine.ztree.repository.ZTreeRepository.findAllByOrderByTId()! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [TId] on this ManagedType [com.github.moregorenine.ztree.domain.ZTree]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.github.moregorenine.TreeStructureZtreeApplication.main(TreeStructureZtreeApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: What about using @query annotation inside your repo?

Comment: Sorry, I did not ask if I would use @query

Comment: Spring Data modules like Spring Data JPA use a parser for creating a query out of repository method names. This parser makes some assumptions about how the method names should be structured. When one runs into an error, there are usually three options - 1. Change class/field names to satisfy the parser - in your case, changing `tId` to `tid` and `OrderByTId` to `OrderByTid` should be sufficient. 2. Change Spring Data module version - try using a lower or higher version to see if you can get rid of the error. 3. Log a bug report with the Spring Data team and wait for them to respond.

Comment: @manish Thank you for your comment, I was trying to report a bug for the first time. But I can't. Because i'm not sure whether it was a bug or not. I am using the 'zTree plugin' to implement the tree structure. that plugin use 'T_ID' parameter. I will try 'tid' or Spring Data JPA Sort.thx.

Answer (score 0):

I Use 'Sort' instead of 'OrderByTid'

`zTrees = zTreeRepository.findAll(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "tId"));`